# Why does my docker container keep starting when I stop it?

Tags: docker

I am simply trying to delete this docker image that is currently running in a container. When I click stop, it immediately starts another container. I cannot delete the image because it constantly says its in use.

Here is Docker Desktop after I just stopped the 2 containers, and you can see another one has spawned without any action from me.[image]

Please let me know if any other information is required

Comment: If you're running it with Kubernetes, then you tell Kubernetes the desired state of your system and k8s starts and stops containers to get to that state. If you just stop a container yourself, k8s sees that and starts it again to get to the desired state. You need to change the desired state and k8s will then stop the container.

Comment: How did you initially start the container?  Do you have a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Those look like the Kubernetes containers that are part of Docker Desktop, and if that's the case you could just turn that feature off.

This is in "Settings" under "Kubernetes": Turn off "Enable Kubernetes"

Comment: ^ this.  Docker Desktop just has visibility to your kubeconfig/kube context and you're seeing it there, but what you have is a kubernetes deployment and not just some ad-hoc container you ran with Docker

Comment: @GlenYu Indeed. Kubernetes is likely going "Huh, that's odd, that pod stopped. Let's restart that!"

Answer (score -2):

Try using the following command in the terminal:

```
docker system prune -a
```

It will clean up unused Docker objects, including images, containers, networks, and volumes.

Keep in mind that the image can be deleted only after all related to it containers are removed.

To remove a docker container use

```
docker rm <container_id>
```

Comment: Since the stated problem is "the container keeps restarting", pruning won't help this case; it can't delete running containers or their corresponding images.